# Clojure: Idiomatic use of atom and ref?

Tags: clojure, idioms, ref, stm

I am working out a bit of Clojure code that will take a ref to a map and increment a key value pair in the map.  I think I am using ref correctly, but Im not sure about atom.  Do I need to use swap! to be more idiomatic?  I am new to STM and Clojure, does this look thread-safe / sane?  What am I missing?

```
(defn increment-key [ref key]
    (dosync
        (if (= (get @ref key) nil)
            (alter ref assoc key (atom 1))
            (alter ref assoc key (atom (inc @(get @ref key)))))))

(defn -main [& args]
    (def my-map (ref {}))
    (increment-key my-map "yellow")
    (println my-map)
    (increment-key my-map "yellow")
    (println my-map))
```

Prints

```
$ lein run
#<Ref@494eaec9: {yellow #<Atom@191410e5: 1>}>
#<Ref@494eaec9: {yellow #<Atom@7461373f: 2>}>
```

Comment: cool, thanks, posted over there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not very idiomatic Clojure to do this: embedding mutable objects within a persistent data structure generally defeats the whole point of immutable data structures.

I would avoid the internal atom entirely, and just have a number associated with the key. Then the entire data structure contained within `my-map` will be immutable.

As for the thread safety: it really depends on how you are going to use it. A `ref` appears to be overkill in this case as it is only really needed when you need to co-ordinate transactions across multiple refs, which you don't have here. Probably an `atom` is sufficient for what you are trying to do.

Here's how you might tackle it instead:

```
(defn increment-key [ref key]
  (swap! ref update-in [key] (fn [n] (if n (inc n) 1))))

(def my-map (atom {}))
(increment-key my-map "yellow")
(println my-map)  ;; => {"yellow" 1}
(increment-key my-map "yellow")
(println my-map)  ;; => {"yellow" 2}
```

**EDIT**: even better would be to keep mutability out of your functions and define increment-key as a pure function.

```
(defn increment-key [m key]
  (assoc m key (if-let [n (m key)] (inc n) 1)))

(def my-map (atom {}))
(swap! my-map increment-key "yellow")
(println my-map)   ;; => {"yellow" 1}
(swap! my-map increment-key "yellow")
(println my-map)   ;; => {"yellow" 2}
```

Comment: I appreciate the response.  I've been thinking a lot about clojure lately and im trying to conceptualize how I would do something that in the imperative world seems to requires state.  For example, a Naive Bayes classifier.  Somewhere, counts have to be talled, and then we have to compute weights from those tallies.  Do you have any advice on how to think about / model what seems inherently "stateful" in the clojure context?  Is there a better way to manage "state" than passing around mutating refs?  I feel like Im about to understand something bigger but am a little stuck...

Comment: I very rarely pass around refs/atoms. Most of my functions in Clojure are pure: they take pure values, and return new changed values. I even wrote an entire game where the world state is a single immutable data structure: https://github.com/mikera/alchemy . The "trick" is to see functions as something that return an updated version of the old data with something changed,

Comment: Wait, doesn't `(lib/setup game)` mutate game which is a mutable PersistentTreeGrid? world.clj:31

Comment: @mikera By the way, `(fn [n] (if n (inc n) 1))` is just `(fnil inc 0)`.

Comment: @David: nope, it returns a new Game with the :lib datastructure initialised. Note that that code is in a `as->` macro block, so `game` is getting re-bound to the result of each operation. This *looks* a bit like mutating state, but it's actually a pure function.